# Greying out (disabling) all other select items when one is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-chosen

I'm working on a multiselect where I need to disable and grey out all other items when the first "all" is selected (and active).  I'm able to select the correct option, but I'm having trouble actually disabling other items when one is selected, then reenabling them when it's deselected.

What comes to mind for me, is to somehow append/remove the "disabled" modifier on each other options when the first is selected.

My code so far:

Jquery

```
    $('.specialty_select_box').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'all'){
            ......
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<select multiple class="specialty_select_box" name="name" data-placeholder="Select All That Apply" id="specialty">
    <option style="font-weight: bold;" value="all">All Specialties</option>
    <option value="1">Balance</option>
    <option value="2">Therapy</option>
    <option value="3">Analysis</option>
    <option value="4">Occ Therapy</option>
    <option value="5">Medicine</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('.specialty_select_box').on('change', function(event) {

  if ($(this).val() == 'all') {
    $('.specialty_select_box option').not(':selected').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  else if ($(this).val() === null) {
     var options = $('.specialty_select_box option:disabled'); 

     if (options.length > 0) {
        options.prop('disabled', false);
     }
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/p9hwJsfilCeMpui4uL6E?p=preview

Comment: Good answers accompany code samples with an explanation for future readers. While the person asking this question may understand your answer, explaining how you arrived at it will help countless others.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to add a class to each single option, for example .singleOption so that you can select all the ones you want to grey out at once, like so:

```
<select multiple class="specialty_select_box" name="name" data-placeholder="Select All That Apply" id="specialty">
    <option style="font-weight: bold;" value="all">All Specialties</option>
    <option class="singleOption" value="1">Balance</option>
    <option class="singleOption" value="2">Therapy</option>
    <option class="singleOption" value="3">Analysis</option>
    <option class="singleOption" value="4">Occ Therapy</option>
    <option class="singleOption" value="5">Medicine</option>
</select>
```

Then when you determine All is selected: select the single options and disable them:

```
$('.specialty_select_box').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'all'){
       $('.singleOption').each(function() {
         $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: Change the if condition to be `('disabled', true);`, then add an else condition to be `('disabled', false);`. That way if the user changes their mind or accidentally clicks the "All Specialties" option, they can deselect it to reenable all the other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

To disable options you can use `$('option').prop('disabled', true);`

You can select all *other* options using `$('option').not(':selected');`

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty much there already, you only needed to implement a way to actually put the disabled attribute on the option elements. This fiddle show the way to do that, plus remove the disabled attributes when the all option gets deselected again: http://jsfiddle.net/ruhar4j6/

```
$('.specialty_select_box').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'all'){
            $(this).find("option").each(function(i, o) {
                if ($(o).val() != "all") {
                    $(o).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(this).find("option").removeAttr("disabled");
        }

    });
```